# HTTP Upgrade to TLS in Nginx Per RFC 2817

Tags: ssl, nginx, https, tls1.2

I have been looking into how I can upgrade an HTTP connection to TLS and achieve and end to end tunnel across proxy hops. I would like to use the client certificate in this tunnel to act upon it on the receiving end after a few hops.
I read [RFC 2817](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2817) (HTTP Upgrade to TLS) and it seems this is possible. I just cannot figure out how to do that using Nginx being new to Nginx.

I was wondering if I am making a complete noob mistake or if this is at all possible in Nginx.

I have Nginx instance 1 with the following config for the http block:

```
http {
  include       mime.types;
  default_type  application/octet-stream;
  log_format main    '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] '
                   '$ssl_protocol/$ssl_cipher '
                   '$ssl_client_cert '
                   '$ssl_client_raw_cert '
                   'HTTP UPGRADE: $http_upgrade '
                   '"$request" $status $body_bytes_sent '
                   '"$http_referer" "$http_user_agent"';

access_log  logs/access.log;

sendfile        on;
keepalive_timeout  65;

map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
    default upgrade;
    ''      close;
}

server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    # Redirect all HTTP requests to HTTPS with a 301 Moved Permanently response.
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

# HTTPS server
server {
    listen       443 ssl;
    listen       [::]:443 ssl;
    server_name  localhost;

    access_log logs/access-ssl.log main;

    ssl_certificate      /root/certs/server.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key  /root/certs/server.key;
    ssl_session_timeout 1d;
    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:50m;
    ssl_session_tickets off;

    # Diffie-Hellman parameter for DHE ciphersuites, recommended 2048 bits
    ssl_dhparam /root/certs/dhparams.pem;

    # modern configuration. tweak to your needs.
    ssl_protocols TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers 'ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256';
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers  on;

    # HSTS (ngx_http_headers_module is required) (15768000 seconds = 6 months)
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security max-age=15768000;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
        proxy_pass https://10.0.3.4/;
    }

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   html;
    }
}
```

The second Nginx instance has the following config has pretty much the same config except for one difference `proxy_pass https://10.0.3.5/index.html`

The last Nginx instance has the following config:

```
http {
include       mime.types;
default_type  application/octet-stream;
log_format main    '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] '
                   '$ssl_protocol/$ssl_cipher '
                   '$ssl_client_cert '
                   '$ssl_client_raw_cert '
                   'HTTP UPGRADE: $http_upgrade '
                   '"$request" $status $body_bytes_sent '
                   '"$http_referer" "$http_user_agent"';

access_log  logs/access.log;

sendfile        on;
keepalive_timeout  65;

map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
    default upgrade;
    ''      close;
}

server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    # Redirect all HTTP requests to HTTPS with a 301 Moved Permanently response.
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

# HTTPS server
server {
    listen       443 ssl;
    listen       [::]:443 ssl;
    server_name  localhost;

    access_log logs/access-ssl.log main;

    ssl_certificate      /root/certs/server.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key  /root/certs/server.key;
    ssl_session_timeout 1d;
    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:50m;
    ssl_session_tickets off;

    # Diffie-Hellman parameter for DHE ciphersuites, recommended 2048 bits
    ssl_dhparam /root/certs/dhparams.pem;

    # modern configuration. tweak to your needs.
    ssl_protocols TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers 'ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256';
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers  on;

    # HSTS (ngx_http_headers_module is required) (15768000 seconds = 6 months)
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security max-age=15768000;

    location / {
        root   html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   html;
    }
}
```

When I hit the URL using HTTPS, I do get the response but nothing about the client cert is printed in the logs. When I use only HTTP, I get the 301 response. These are the two calls I am making:
`$ curl -k -i  --cert /root/certs/client-cert.pem --key /root/certs/client-key.pem --header "Upgrade: TLS/1.2" --header "Connection: Upgrade"  https://10.0.3.3/`

and

`$ curl -k -i  --cert /root/certs/client-cert.pem --key /root/certs/client-key.pem --header "Upgrade: TLS/1.2" --header "Connection: Upgrade"  http://10.0.3.3/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RFC 2817 defines two methods for TLS upgrade: CONNECT request and `Connection: Upgrade`.

CONNECT is a HTTP request done by the browser when using an explicitly configured HTTP proxy. It gets not used with transparent proxies or reverse proxies. Contrary to for instance [squid](http://www.squid-cache.org/) nginx is a web server and not a HTTP proxy (from the perspective of the browser) and thus does not implement the CONNECT request.

As for the Connection Upgrade to TLS specified in RFC 2817: this was just an idea and no browser supports this. This kind of Upgrade mechanisms is actually used in browsers today but not for upgrading to TLS but only for WebSockets.

Comment: Thank you so much for the clarification. I am planning on using this feature implemented at the application level and I don't plan to use it with the browser. The idea is having an application make a call, presenting its own certificate, and being proxied all the way to a service with a resource that is requested. There are multiple hops to reach the end service and the end service will authenticate and authorize the request based on the original sender's cert.

Comment: @Tempo: Because TLS is end-to-end encryption only the endpoint can request and validate the client certificate. This means that it is not possible to choose the endpoint by the client certificate or the requested resource in some software in the middle (nginx or whatever) and still be able to forward the client certificate to the endpoint unharmed.

Comment: Thank you so much for your comments, very appreciated. If TLS (and HTTPS tunnel/upgrade) is not an options in this case, is there any other proven solution I can use to achieve the desired result? Besides implementing a custom protocol from scratch? Even for a proprietary protocol, I am not even sure how to begin implementing it. As an Nginx module perhaps?

Comment: @Tempo: This is a follow-up question which cannot be answered in a comment. I would recommend to ask this in a new question which clearly describes what you want to achieve at the end and also the use case for you problem. It might just that you need to step back a bit and not focus on a specific solution but think about how to solve the (unknown) general problem in other ways.

Comment: Thank you so much Steffen, I'm evaluating other approaches to this problem.